# Using javascript to search for anchor title attribute

Tags: javascript, search, attributes, anchor, title

I have a javascript search function to search through a list of links.

```
function search() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue, title;
input = document.getElementById("srch");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("sites");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText || a.title;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";

    }
}
```

}

and a list of links as such:

```
<li><span><a title="hippo" href="https://site1.com" target="_blank">site1.com</a> : Big grey animals</span></li>
<li><span><a title="apple" href="http://site2.com" target="_blank">site2.com</a> : roundish fruit</span></li>
<li><span><a title="couch" href="https://site3.com" target="_blank">site3.com</a> : big soft things to sit on</span></li>
<li><span><a title="lemon" href="https://site4.com" target="_blank">site4.com</a> : sour fruits with two points</span></li>
```

For the most part it works great but fails to account for the title attribute. So if a user were to search for one of the keywords, it will not display. I've tried several variations but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement is to search for a string both within the text contained in an element and within an element title.

The main problem in the given code comes here:

```
a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText || a.title;
```

There's a couple of things. First, the 'a' is not in fact the a element, it is the first span (which contains the a). Second, Javascript will evaluate the values given in an OR in order, so if the first is true it doesn't bother to go on and evaluate the others. You aren't getting a string concatenated with the different values, you are getting the value of the first one (if it exists) and if not the second one and so on.

Here is a snippet which rectifies these two problems, it's rather wordy so as to spell out what is happening.

```js
function search() {
var input, filter, ul, li, span, a, i, txtValue, title;
input = document.getElementById("srch");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("sites");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    span = li[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0];    
    txtValue = span.textContent || span.innerText;
    a = span.firstChild;
    title = a.title;
    if ((txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) || (title.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
```

```html
<input id="srch"/><button onclick="search()">Search</button>
<ul id="sites">
<li><span><a title="hippo" href="https://site1.com" target="_blank">site1.com</a> : Big grey animals</span></li>
<li><span><a title="apple" href="http://site2.com" target="_blank">site2.com</a> : roundish fruit</span></li>
<li><span><a title="couch" href="https://site3.com" target="_blank">site3.com</a> : big soft things to sit on</span></li>
<li><span><a title="lemon" href="https://site4.com" target="_blank">site4.com</a> : sour fruits with two points</span></li>
</ul>
```